# What is the default text color for Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar?

Tags: android

I need to find the text color code for Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar. Not for the action bar, just the default (grey) color code for normal text. I presume the text color is set in this theme.

Comment: Screen shot some default text. and inspect the image for its colour.

Comment: thanks, thought of that, was just wondering was there a way to check the theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Theme details, by keep going to parent theme details.

Ctl + Click on parent theme inside style.xml will navigate you to parent theme details.